# Set a Prompt when using CSV as a Data Source in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

Normally in the query builder you can add a prompt on a specific dimension, and if you add a custom query outside of the query builder you can type your prompt into the SQL.

In my current situation, I have a report that has several CSV data sources as opposed to my normal MySQL tables. Is there a way to add a prompt from the CSV data source like you would SQL?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "prompt"

Comment: In the 'Modify Command' window in the Database Expert, here's where it is for an SQL query: `WHERE x = "{?prompt}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly.

You could:

1. create multiple versions of the report
2. add one subreport for each CSV file; conditionally suppress all subreports except the one that matches a parameter value
3. programatically change the CSV before viewing it (only an option if you have built a custom application)
4. if you are using BusinessObjects Enterprise, you could create multiple scheduled instances, each of which references a given CSV

Comment: This is what I figured. It's a bit too complicated for any of these - decided to just import the CSV into a database.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to use a Parameter in Crystal Reports.  The parameter will pop up an prompt for input when you run the report.
1.  Add a parameter to the CSV Report in the field Explorer
[image]
2.  Click on the Select Expert and select the field that you want to filter on.
3.  Set the criteria to **is equal to** and select your parameter value.
*Your parameter field has to be the same value type as the field which shouldn't be a big deal when dealing with CSV files.*

[image]